# Connection refused HTTP (port 80)

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, http, connection, apache2

So I'm very much a novice when it comes to Apache and Ubuntu, but I know the basics (file moving, copying, editing, etc).

I was trying to remedy a problem with PHP's permissions, so I set `/tmp/` and `/var/tmp/` permissions to 777 using `chmod`. Then, I modified both `php.ini` files, in `/etc/php/` and `/etc/php5/`, to customize the temp directory. However, I ended up rebooting the server without actually creating the temp directory (oops).

Now I can still connect to my server through SFTP, but in Chrome when I try to connect it gives me an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I thought it was a problem with `.php` pages, so I tried loading an `.html` page. Nothing. I've tried rebooting several more times, but to no avail.

In addition, my whole filesystem is read-only. So I'm assuming I messed up something in config and as a safety measure, everything is locked down. I have tried `sudo su`, remounting the drive (blocked because I can't write to some config file), and a bunch of other stuff. I also get an error when doing `fsck`: `fsck.ext4: unable to resolve UUID: xxxxxxxx`. Again, can't auto fix any errors through remounting because I can't write to some config file.

I tried going through system logs in `/var/log/`, but I couldn't find any error messages. I believe this is a problem with PHP config, but I'm not sure. I also looked at my UFW, and saw it was disabled. When trying to enable it, again, it wouldn't let me because I couldn't write to the file system. All of this is in `sudo`.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I managed to find my bash history as root, but nothing seems too weird: https://pastebin.com/yPh5rSE6

**EDIT 2:** One thing I remember is while modifying permissions for `/var/tmp/`, the folder had a sticky bit; I believe the permission was `drwxrwxrwt`. Was changing this a server breaking blunder? I cannot change this because I'm mounted as a read-only file system.

**EDIT 3:** So it seems like the issue is something with permissions, which caused an error on start up and locked the file system to read-only, messing up the web server. How plausible does this sound? The issue seems to be rooted with the UUID error showing up in two places, `fsck` and `mount`. How do I solve this?

Comment: If the whole file system is read-only,  the problem is something way wider than PHP's configuration. Also, giving wide `777` permissions even temporarily is reckless. Probably you have messed something up while doing this kind of random testing with file permissions.

Comment: Bash history for root before this reboot  could give a clue on what went wrong. It's also likely that restoring from backups is the easiest solution. Be more careful next time.

Comment: Where can I find bash history for root?

Comment: @EsaJokinen I figured it out, added it to my question as a pastebin link: nothing seems too out of the ordinary.

Comment: Both `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` had sticky bit, that shouldn't under any circuimstances make root file system mounted read-only. You need to figure out why that happens first before fixing the web server. Your description of why remounting fails is very confusing - you mean sudo fails or the remount fails? Show us the errors!

Comment: @MarekRost I tried `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` and it gives me `mount: can't find UUID=xxx`. This is the same UUID from `fsck`. Perhaps this is the main problem? Sorry about the confusing description, I got varying errors at different times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unusual for system to spontaneously start mounting root partition as read-only. The UUID error suggests something wrong with `/etc/fstab` file and hard drive detection.

First attempt to remount the root partition `rw` with explicitly setting the partition name. Use the command `df` to show which partition is mounted as `/`. Then use the `sudo mount -o remount,rw` with both location of the partition and `/`.

After this was hopefully successful, it's time to debug the read-only boot. Verify the state of `/etc/fstab` file. Is the syntax correct? Do all drives and partitions specified here really exist? Are there no explicit `ro` mount options for the `/` mount point? If the file contains any UUIDs, check that they exist in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` and check that these files are links to existing drive partitions.

After you've corrected any possible errors with `/etc/fstab` reboot the machine and fix the permissions on `tmp` folders if they haven't been fixed automatically.

If remounting the root partition in `rw` mode still fails with explicit drive location, check for possible damage to the hard drive. Look into output of `dmesg` command and consult internet for any messages suggesting I/O problems. If you have `smart` installed use the command `sudo smartctl -a /dev/<drive>` to verify it has not been damaged.

Get back to us after you've tried all this.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help, I successfully remounted the drive (`sudo mount -o remount rw /`), but I don't know what to do with `fstab`. This is the one line written in the file: `UUID=815063a9-c956-44a6-ab11-05e1d0bb3a58 / ext4    errors=remount-ro 0   1`. What does this mean, and how do I fix it? I can confirm this is the same UUID from other errors.

Comment: So I looked in `/dev/disk/by-uuid` and there is only one UUID; however, it is different from the one before.

Comment: Nvm, I copied over the UUID from `by-uuid` into `fstab` and rebooted, works like a charm! Thanks so much!